# Program to print N first factorial numbers in c

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, factorial

Factorial number is a number that is multiplied by it's previous numbers. For example it's 5. 1*2*3*4*5 is it's factorial number.
I already made a program which prints factorial of any number, but i don't know how to make it to print N first factorial number in c.
For example i type 10. It must show first 10 numbers along with their factorials (Making a table)
Here is what i was made to print factorial of any number.Is there any possibility to do with while/ if else statements/ and for loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, n, fakt = 1;
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
         fakt = fakt*i;
    printf("Factorial of %d js %d\n", n, fakt);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please use braces. They are handy. You do not want to get caught with your trousers down!

Comment: Don't forget to consider the limitations of your program. If `n` is too big, you might get an overflow and the calculated factorial will be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this:

**Program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, n, fakt = 1;
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=1;i<= n;i++) //use braces to write more than one statement inside the loop
    {
         fakt=fakt*i;
         printf("Factorial of %d is %d\n", i, fakt);
    }
    getch();
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a number:
5
Factorial of 1 is 1
Factorial of 2 is 2
Factorial of 3 is 6
Factorial of 4 is 24
Factorial of 5 is 120
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int f=1,i,v;

    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the number :");
    scanf("%d",&v);
        for(i=1;i<=v;i++)
        {
            f=f*i;
            printf("num =%d and fac=%d\n",i,f);
        }
    getch();
}
```

this code will work

Answer (score 0):

That code already uses the `for` loop. The `while` loop equivalent is:

```
i = 1;
while (i <= n) {
    fakt = fakt*i;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a nested loop.

Run the parent loop from 1 to n,
and the nested loop will be your already working for loop.

You may want this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
            int n, i, num, factorial;
            printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);

            for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                    num = i;
                    factorial = 1;
                    while(num)
                            factorial *= num--;
                    printf("%d \t %d\n", i, factorial);
            }
            return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
    Enter the number of terms: 10
    1    1
    2    2
    3    6
    4    24
    5    120
    6    720
    7    5040
    8    40320
    9    362880
    10   3628800
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int factorial(int n)
{
    int i,fakt = 1;
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
       fakt = fakt*i;
    return fakt;
}

int main()
{
   int n;
   printf("Enter a number:\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   int i = 0;
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       printf("Factorial for %d is %d\n",i,factorial(i));
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I think this will do the job just fine.

Comment: How about the complexity?

Comment: Trying to make it a little more complex?

Comment: Well, this one takes O(n^2) time. If you are looking for better complexity then yeah your answer is more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this fastest version of factorial using recursion with if ..else statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fact(int n);
void main()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nEnter an integer:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fact(n);
}
int fact(int n)
{
    int a;
    if(n==0)
    {
            printf("The Factorial of 0 is 1\n");                                                                                                   
            return 1;
    }
    else
    {
            a=n*fact(n-1);
            printf("The Factorial of %d is %d\n",n,a);
            return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ reza.safiyat,Have you checked this code is not working ?It's working so only I have posted this answer .

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(int n){
    int fact;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a number and type exit:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n!=0){
    fact=n*main(n-1);
    printf("Factorial of %d is %d\n",n,fact);
    getch();
    return fact;
    }
    else{
    printf("Factorial of 0 is 1.\n");
    getch();
    return 1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: You should include commentary or at least a basic description rather than uncommented code